# Slider elements animation delay

Tags: css, animation, delay

I want to make an image slider with sliding up texts and button. I want the elements appear delayed but its not working, first every elements load and then the animation runs.

Here is my code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hnorbi/bsko53jr/7/)

```css
@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
    padding-top: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding-top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .slide-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    width: 50%;
    animation: slide-up 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  .slide-text {
    line-height: 1.75;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 60px 0;
    animation: slide-up 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  .slide-btn {
    animation: slide-up 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-heading">Lorem Ipsum </div>
<div class="slide-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas venenatis est metus, ac viverra quam rutrum vitae. Phasellus eget egestas arcu. Nulla porttitor at justo egestas ornare. </div>
<div class="slide-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">More</button></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `animation-fill-mode: backwards;`

> CSS animations do not affect the element before the first keyframe is played or after the last keyframe is played. The animation-fill-mode property can override this behavior.
>
> backwards ---> The element will get the style values that is set by the
>   first keyframe (depends on animation-direction), and retain this
>   during the animation-delay period

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-fill-mode.asp

Try this:

```
@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
    padding-top: 100px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    padding-top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .slide-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    width: 50%;
    animation: slide-up 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
  .slide-text {
    line-height: 1.75;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 60px 0;
    animation: slide-up 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
  .slide-btn {
    animation: slide-up 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
}
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

What is creating problem in your animation is the padding, you know padding take distance from the above element, so here in your case you have to add translate property to animate your texts one by one without affecting each other, just like that:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700&display=swap');

     .slide-heading {
        font-size: 50px;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 900;
        margin: 100px 0 30px 0;
        width: 75%;
        animation: slide-up 2s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-delay: 1s;
      }
      .slide-text {
        line-height: 1.75;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
        width: 60%;
        margin: 0 0 60px 0;
        animation: slide-up 5s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-delay: 1s;
      }
      .slide-btn {
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
        animation: slide-up 5s;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        animation-delay: 1s;
      }
@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
      transform: translateY(100px);
      opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="slide-heading">Lorem Ipsum </div>
<div class="slide-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas venenatis est metus, ac viverra quam rutrum vitae. Phasellus eget egestas arcu. Nulla porttitor at justo egestas ornare. </div>
<div class="slide-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">More</button></div>
```

It works I have tested it. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The mixed suggestions are worked, thanks @Farhan Ali and @mkasp98

```
@keyframes slide-up {
  from {
      transform: translateY(100px);
      opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0);
      opacity: 1;
  }
}
.slide-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
    width: 50%;
    animation: slide-up 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
.slide-text {
    line-height: 1.75;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 60px 0;
    animation: slide-up 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }
.slide-btn {
    animation: slide-up 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 3s;
}



    <div class="slide-heading">Lorem Ipsum </div>
    <div class="slide-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas venenatis est metus, ac viverra quam rutrum vitae. Phasellus eget egestas arcu. Nulla porttitor at justo egestas ornare. </div>
    <div class="slide-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">More</button></div>
```